# Как сделать чтобы окно которое под контролем Vue рендерилось после загрузки данных

Tags: vue.js

Есть сайт, на нем модальное окно, к которому привязан Vue. И на окошке висит директива `v-if`, которая изначально прячет окно, но при загрузке сайта, это окно рендерится, и через доли секунды прячется. Такая-же ситуация с полями типа `{{ field }}`. Как это решить? Скрипт с vue лежит отдельно, а шаблон в основном файле.

Comment: Странно, что при v-if  элемент рендерится. Может с условием что- то не так? Покажите код

Comment: Вопрос давно решен, смысл помечать как дубликат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте директиву `v-cloak` на корневом или дочернем элементе Vue приложения:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

> Эта директива останется на элементе до тех пор, пока связанный с ним экземпляр Vue не закончит компиляцию. *--[источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak)*

К данной директиве можно применять привила `css` для скрытия элемента как к обычному атрибуту.

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    // Модель, отвечающая за
    // отображение модального окна.
    shownModal: false,
  },

  methods: {
    toggleModal() {
      this.shownModal = !this.shownModal
    },

    closeModal() {
      this.shownModal = false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/*
  Скрытие элемента по атрибуту.
  Когда экземпляр будет готов,
  этот атрибут будет удален.
*/

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <button type="button" @click="toggleModal">Переключить окно</button>

  <div class="modal" v-if="shownModal">
    <p>Сообщение из модального окна</p>
    <button type="button" @click="closeModal">Закрыть окно</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)