# vue.js отрисовка template после получения данных

Tags: vue.js

Есть сайт он получается данные через ajax но при загрузке страницы на долю секунды отрисовываются крякозябры т.к. данные с ajax еще не получены как мне остановить отрисовку template пока не загрузился объект, я попробовал установить setTimeout но не помогло: вот ссылка [ССылка на сайт из примера](https://do-zarplati.kz/#)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982753/256824

Comment: добавьте сюда минимально необходимый код компонента

Answer (score 0):

Если сайт при первой загрузке должен что-то откуда-то подтянуть, то я делаю следующим образом. В хуке `created()` делаю запрос по урлу, и жду инфу. Как придёт, отрисовываю страницу. Тут важно не забыть пометить хук асинком. Выглядит примерно так:

```
async created() {
  const result = await axios.get('/targetUrl');
  // дальше result.data уже распихивается по нужным переменным
}
```

Так же можно юзать хуки роутера, вроде `beforeRouteEnter()`. А вообще в следующий раз просто создай сниппет с минимальным количеством кода для описания проблемы. Очень часто просто сам в итоге обнаруживаешь ошибку на маленьком примере.